# Command 'roswtf' not found,installation failed

Tags: ros-melodic, roscore, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to solve it?

```
$ roswtf
Command 'roswtf' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python-roswtf

$ sudo apt install python-roswtf
[sudo] dean 的密码： 
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树       
正在读取状态信息... 完成       
有一些软件包无法被安装。如果您用的是 unstable 发行版，这也许是
因为系统无法达到您要求的状态造成的。该版本中可能会有一些您需要的软件
包尚未被创建或是它们已被从新到(Incoming)目录移出。
下列信息可能会对解决问题有所帮助：

下列软件包有未满足的依赖关系：
 python-roswtf : 依赖: python-rosservice 但是它将不会被安装
                 依赖: python-rosmsg 但是它将不会被安装
                 依赖: python-roslaunch 但是它将不会被安装
                 依赖: python-rosnode 但是它将不会被安装
                 依赖: python-roslib 但是它将不会被安装
E: 无法修正错误，因为您要求某些软件包保持现状，就是它们破坏了软件包间的依赖关
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348609/command-%27roswtf%27-not-found,installation-failed./) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-07**:
For future questions: please refrain from posting questions in languages other than English.

In this case, the main question was in English, so that's OK. But if error messages or other information is not in English, it'll make it very difficult for others to help you.

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-04-07**:
Ok!
From now, I will do everything only in English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. `python-roswtf` is the wrong package. Please uninstall it using `sudo apt purge python-roswtf`. This is the correct package to install:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-roswtf
```

As a side note, if you want to install any ros packages via `apt`, you can just search the [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf) for a package (in this case, roswtf) and typically how you would install it is with the package name `ros-DISTRIBUTION-PACKAGENAME`. In the case of roswtf, the package name on the ros wiki is `roswtf`, and I assume you are using ros-melodic, so you can install it using the package name `ros-melodic-roswtf`. If the package you are installing has an underscore in it, for example [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base), the package name to install via apt becomes `ros-melodic-move-base` where the underscore in move_base has been replaced with a hyphen (move-base). This naming convention generally true for most packages on the ros wiki (but maybe not all packages).

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) with karma: 228 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-04-07**:
Yes,it helps,now,it works correctly.
You are so great for your side note.
I believe it will help me more in the future and more people.
Thank you so much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-07**:\

> `python-roswtf` is the wrong package

Indeed. And see [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) for more information.

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-13**:
You are welcome. Glad I could help!